# Angular (or any HttpClient). Catching an error with status code 0 in app, but status code NOT_ZERO in chrome devtools?

Tags: angular, http, cors

Is it possible to catch an error code after CORS error?

Chrome console when i want to catch a error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://backend-domain/api' from origin 'http://frontend-domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Error received through a pipe with a catchError

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://backend-domain/api', ok: false, …}
```

And finally, real code which i want to catch.

```
POST http://backend-domain/api net::ERR_FAILED REAL_ERROR_CODE (REAL_ERROR_DESCRIPTION)
```

Most likely this is some kind of architectural issues. Front-back works fine. If you do not cause an error on the back, then there will be no CORS error at the front.

I tried different ways to catch the error, but, first of all, the pipe (with catchError inside) for the POST method gives status code 0.